# Shortcut key for monospaced character format in Confluence

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, formatting, confluence

I know the `{{...}}` markup but it's rather cumbersome.

Is there a shortcut key to set the selected text to monospace in Confluence or is it possible to set up one somehow?

Comment: I just came across this. This is not supported so far, see the following issue: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-23966.

Comment: @AndreasKlöber: Thank you! I've just voted for the JIRA ticket.

Answer (score 6):

The way I do this is pretty simple, I added a bookmark/shortcut that executes the click on the monospace button like so:

```
javascript:$('#rte-monospace').click();
```

If you use Google Chrome, simply right click bookmark bar, choose "Add Page" and add the javascript snippet in the "URL" field, with any "Name".

E.g:

[image: screenshot]

---

You can also add a keyboard shortcut to the function, using tinyMce's interface directly. Again adding a snippet in a bookmark bar is easiest:

```
javascript:tinyMCE.activeEditor.addShortcut("ctrl+alt+m","monospace","confMonospace");
```

Clicking the shortcut enables a toggle toggles the shortcut for the current page. Using it by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> will mark the selected text as monospaced.

This was mentioned in the [related JIRA issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-23966) as commented by @ andreas-klöber.

---

For bonus points, get [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and paste in your user script, and update the matching urls to always execute on your confluence domain. Here is an example for the official atlassian confluence site:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Toggle Confluence monospace with ctrl+alt+m
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.2
// @description  add keyboard shortcut to toggle monospace styling for selected text
// @author       Pavel Savshenko
// @match        https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/editpage.action*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    if (tinyMCE && tinyMCE.activeEditor)  {
        console.log("Monospace patch loading");
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.addShortcut("ctrl+alt+m","monospace","confMonospace");
    }
})();
```

This again comes from a comment in the JIRA issue mentioned.